# Cgridview row update and version number increase

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I am new in php & using yii framework.Can any one please help me with an issue i am facing.I have a grid view page with a update button.when i update any information of my row in the grid view it works fine.But if by mistake i enter any wrong entry and want to update the information it should first check if there is any entry of the data before.if there is a data entry before, then the version number will increase with a id. and if there is no data entry before then there will create a new data with a new id.

here is my Controller update action code:

```
    public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=new CvUpload;
    $Updatemodel= new CvUpload;
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    $CvHistory=new CvHistory;   
    if(isset($_POST['CvUpload']))

    {
        $model_unchanged = $this->loadModel($id);
        $model_changed = $this->loadModel($id);
        $model->attributes=$_POST['CvUpload'];  
        $Updatemodel->attributes=$_POST['CvUpload']
        if ($model_unchanged->user_id == $_POST['CvUpload']['user_id'] && $model_unchanged->job_title_id == $_POST['CvUpload']['job_title_id'] && $model_unchanged->file_name == $_POST['CvUpload']['file_name']){ 
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model_unchanged->cv_id));

          }           
          elseif($model_changed->user_id !== $_POST['CvUpload']['user_id'] && $model_changed->job_title_id !== $_POST['CvUpload']['job_title_id'] && $model_changed->file_name !== $_POST['CvUpload']['file_name'] && $model_changed->version_id !== $_POST['CvUpload']['version_id'])
          {
            $model_changed->save(false);
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->condition = "cv_id = $model_changed->cv_id AND is_current = 'yes'";
            $CvHistory = CvHistory::model()->find($criteria);
            $CvHistory->is_current = 'no';
            $CvHistory->status = 'inactive';
            if($CvHistory->save(false))
            {
                    $new_CvHistory=new CvHistory;

                $new_CvHistory->cv_id  = $model_changed->cv_id;
                $new_CvHistory->user_id  = $model_changed->user_id;
                $new_CvHistory->job_title_id  = $model_changed->job_title_id;
                $new_CvHistory->cv_type  = $model_changed->cv_type;
                $new_CvHistory->version_id  = $CvHistory->version_id+1;
                $model_changed->version_id = $new_CvHistory->version_id ;
                $new_CvHistory->file_name  = $model_changed->file_name;
                $new_CvHistory->upload_date  = $model_changed->upload_date;
                $new_CvHistory->update_date  = new CDbExpression("NOW()");
                $model_changed->update_date = $new_CvHistory->update_date ;

                $new_CvHistory->status  = $model_changed->status;
                $new_CvHistory->is_current  = "yes";
                $new_CvHistory->save(false);
                $model_changed->save(false);
                if($new_CvHistory->save(false))$this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model_changed->cv_id));
            }
          }         
        elseif($model->save())// if
        {
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->condition = "cv_id = $model->cv_id AND is_current = 'yes'";
            $CvHistory = CvHistory::model()->find($criteria);
            $CvHistory->is_current = 'no';
            $CvHistory->status = 'inactive';

            if($CvHistory->save(false))
            {
                $new_CvHistory=new CvHistory;

                $new_CvHistory->cv_id  = $model->cv_id;
                $new_CvHistory->user_id  = $model->user_id;
                $new_CvHistory->job_title_id  = $model->job_title_id;
                $new_CvHistory->cv_type  = $model->cv_type;
                $new_CvHistory->version_id  = $CvHistory->version_id+1;
                $model->version_id = $new_CvHistory->version_id ;
                $new_CvHistory->file_name  = $model->file_name;
                $new_CvHistory->upload_date  = $model->upload_date;
                $new_CvHistory->update_date  = new CDbExpression("NOW()");
                $model->update_date = $new_CvHistory->update_date ;

                $new_CvHistory->status  = $model->status;
                $new_CvHistory->is_current  = "yes";
                $new_CvHistory->save(false);
                $model->save(false);
                if($new_CvHistory->save(false))$this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->cv_id));

            }

        }   
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'CvHistory'=>$CvHistory,

    ));
}
```

Can any one give me a solution for the problem i am facing.

Comment: Please provide only relevant code. Right now it's hard to understand what you have written in code

Comment: ok...do i need to post the question again or i can post the code in comment.. @Justinas

Comment: i have an idea to solve the problem but do not know how to do in code.I need to change in the Controller mainly.I need to load the model first in a array,then i from the array i would have to run a for loop to get the latest id,then check if the is in the grid view or not.If the id exists then just need to increase the version number and if the id is new in the grid view then it will create a new row in the grid view.but i do not know how to code all this.As i am very poor at coding....@Justinas

Comment: You can edit your question to minimize code

Comment: I have edited the question ...@Justinas